# Sqlite column fails to create in creation time

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing a strange problem. I'm creating a db in sqlite with the below query

```
String GROUP_TABLE = "groups";
String ROW_ID = "rowid";
String GROUP_ID = "GroupID";
String GROUP_NAME = "GroupName";
String GROUP_STATUS = "GroupStatus";
String IS_ADMIN = "IsAdmin";
String GROUP_TYPE = "GroupType";
String IS_PUBLIC = "IsPublic";
String LAST_UPDATE = "LastUpdate";

String groupQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ GROUP_TABLE +" ("
        +ROW_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        +GROUP_ID+" TEXT, "
        +GROUP_NAME+" TEXT, "
        +GROUP_STATUS+" TEXT, "
        +GROUP_TYPE+" TEXT, "
        +IS_ADMIN+" TEXT, "
        +IS_PUBLIC+" TEXT, "
        +LAST_UPDATE+" TEXT);";
```

This is the schema given by sqlite adb command

```
H:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open mydb.db
sqlite> .full schema
Usage: .fullschema
sqlite> .fullschema
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
CREATE TABLE groups (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, GroupID TEXT, GroupName     TEXT, GroupStatus TEXT, GroupType TEXT, IsAdmin TEXT, IsPubli
c TEXT, LastUpdate TEXT);
/* No STAT tables available */
```

and when I enter records for the first time there will be no problem. But when I try to enter records next time i get

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table groups has no column named LastUpdate
11-04 14:35:01.850  11947-11974/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting         GroupType=1 GroupID=553 LastUpdate=2015-08-08T14:17:14.000Z IsAdmin=1     GroupName=SAIFOOTWEARS GroupStatus=1
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table groups has no column named     LastUpdate (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO     groups(GroupType,GroupID,LastUpdate,IsAdmin,GroupName,GroupStatus) VALUES     (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

And when I check the schema again the column is missing.

```
H:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open mydb.db
sqlite> .fullschema
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
CREATE TABLE groups ( rowId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,GroupID TEXT, GroupName     TEXT,GroupStatus TEXT,IsAdmin TEXT, GroupType TEXT, IsPublic
TEXT);
/* No STAT tables available */
```

Any leads on this would be of great help.

Comment: You possibly added that column **after** the database was aleady created by a previous app run. Uninstall and reinstall your app. DONE.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() method of sqliteOpenHelpers called when the database is created for the first time. This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should happen.

I think first time when you created your database you don't include LastUpdate column. Later you included it.but your table is created first time.So when adb get same database version for your app it dose not update your database.

So try this
Change your databse version no. Or uninstall app from your phone and run it again.

If problem does not solve.Then please provide full code of your class in Question.

Comment: I have already declared the column name LastUpdate in onCreate and I have tried uninstalling the app, upgrading the db, but still I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I may help you. please provide full code of your class in Question.